# How to take the opposite of the long regex?

Tags: regex

I know that [^9] and [^1-9] are allowed in regex, but I am having trouble compiling the opposite of this:

`^(<\?php[\w\W]*\?>/);`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using perl compatible regex syntax (you probably are, though you don't specify your platform), the `(?!)` construct can do this.  That is, "a(?!b)"  will match "ac", but not "ab".

Comment: You need to be more specific about your test if you want more help.  You're saying that the match string returned by the match is only "a"?  Yes, that's correct.  The `(?!...)` expression is zero width.  What exactly are you trying to do?